# Is there a way to make my touchscreen monitor work sooner after startup?

Tags: windows-8.1, touchscreen

I recently got an iBUYPOWER desktop tower and a 24" acer touchscreen monitor, which I absolutely love.
My only problem is, while my computer starts up from a powered off state very quickly(less than 5 seconds usually), I sometimes have to wait as long as 20-30 seconds for the touchscreen monitor to start recognizing my finger touches.  I'm running Windows 8.1 which requires a password or pin to unlock the computer after it's been off, and I like to use the touchscreen to enter my pin, so I'd rather not have to wait.  I've been forced to use mouse and keyboard to sign in, which is obviously just a convenience issue, but like I said, I'd like to have my finger touches recognized as soon as my computer starts up.
Is this a BIOS thing?  Can I change some kind of boot order so my computer loads up the monitor right after it loads up the OS?  If you need more info about my computer or hardware, please leave a comment.

Comment: If you wait long enough, does it eventually let you use the touchscreen to log in, or does the touchscreen only work after you've logged in?

Comment: If I wait long enough it works.  I'm just impatient xp